# Time condition not changing background automatically

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created simple index.html with time condition what should change opacity of div element.

It does not change on its own, everytime I need to reload the whole page. What am I doing wrong?

main.js

```
window.onload = function() {
// TODO:: Do your initialization job

var cs = new Date();
var hour = cs.getHours();
var minu = cs.getMinutes();
var sec = cs.getSeconds();
var tst = hour +":"+ minu +":"+ sec;

// day1 to day 2 transition

      function day1today20(){
    if('10:00' <= tst&&tst < '15:57:20')
        {
            document.getElementById("day1").style.opacity = "1";
            document.getElementById("night3").style.opacity = "0";  

        }     
     setTimeout(day1today20, 100);   
}
              day1today20();                  


  function day1today2(){
    if('15:57:21' <= tst&&tst < '15:58:00')
        {
            document.getElementById("day1").style.opacity = "0";
            document.getElementById("night3").style.opacity = "1";

        }                        
    setTimeout(day1today2, 100);               
}

                   day1today2(); 
};
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, 
 maximum-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="test watch" />

<title>test watch</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">    


    <img id="day1" src="C:\Users\user\Desktop\index test\images\day1.png" style="opacity: 0"/>   
    <img id="night3" src="C:\Users\user\Desktop\index test\images\night3.png" style="opacity: 0"/>  

<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

What am I doing wrong, why night3 is not loading automatically and I need to reload the page?

Comment: `setTimeout` these only happen once, 100 milliseconds after your page is loaded.

Comment: so it should be `setInterval` ?

Comment: Yes, but checking every 100 milliseconds seems overkill,..  Maybe up them to 1000 (1 second)

Comment: It supposed to be watches, I just couldnt add whole code. But when i had setInterval setted up digital watch was freezing a lot Should i make it more than one second?

Comment: It's hard to tell what problem your having here, even 100ms shouldn't be causing freezing issues.   Have you a working example, maybe knock up a jsBin, or even better a snippet here to show the problem..

Comment: I can add pastebin in main thread. Give me moment

Comment: jsBin is better here it is: [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/huvoluk/1/edit?html,css,js,output) Just edit time in condition. I hope you get my point what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @Keith let me know if you checked it. Thank you